# C++ Makefile Which Uses The Correct Source File?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu

I want to type the following:

```
make fileName.cpp
```

To compile, and then to execute:

```
./fileName
```

If I have a make file like this:

```
commandToCompileFileName:
    g++ -o fileName fileName.cpp
```

Then I can do:

```
make commandToCompileFileName
```

And then:

```
./fileName
```

I want to be able to do this with different files, without having to write a different prompt for each of them in makefile. So something would be in place of

```
commandToCompileFileName
```

in the makefile that would just compile whatever I type in after make, and the executable would just be named the same minus the .cpp.

This [page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) in the very first paragraph describes precisely what I want and probably answers my question, yet I couldn't figure it out after playing around with '$@' and '$<'.

Comment: You have to give make the name of the final target you want to be built, not the name of the source file.  So you shouldn't type `make fileName.cpp`, you should type `make fileName`.  Make always starts with the _final target_ and works its way backwards, using prerequisite definitions, to find the source file(s) needed to build that target.

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not need a Makefile to do this: make ships with a whole bunch of default rules, one of which creates programs from `.cpp` files.

In other words, just type `make fileName`, and be happy :)

(if you want to custom compilation flags, see the `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` variables)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

```
run_% : %
    @echo "---- running $< ----"
    $<

.PHONY : run_%
```

So that when you do, for example, `make run_test` it builds `test` target and runs it.